# Prism: how to load modules from directory by command from another module

Tags: c#, wpf, prism, mef, modularity

I have a composite app builded with Prism and MEF which contains a few modules.
User can load any combination of them - they are fully independent and created for specific needs.

Now I need a "second level" - a new "main" module that could load its "submodules".
This "submodules" are placed in a separate dlls and should be loaded from a directory by a command from a "main" module.

The "main" module don't know anyting about its "submodules", even the number of them.

What is a good solution for this module loading scenario?

Does I need a second `Shell` as a "main" module?

Thanks!